# Get month wise yearly report in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

all I have a employee table with the following fields employee name, wages date, wages I want to sum records month-wise.here is table data. I m using oracle database 11g

[image: employee records]

and here is the output I want.

[image: result]

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text for data and code.

Comment: What have you tried for yourself? This is not a free coding service, and you will typically get better responses if you show what you've tried for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROLLUP` in your `GROUP BY`

```
WITH t(NAME, dt, w) AS (
    SELECT 'adam', DATE '2020-01-01', 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'adam', DATE '2020-02-01', 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'adam', DATE '2020-03-01', 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'jhone', DATE '2020-01-01', 100 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'jhone', DATE '2020-02-01', 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'jhone', DATE '2020-03-01', 151 FROM dual
    )
SELECT NAME, NVL(TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmMon'), 'total') AS mon, SUM(w) AS sum_w
FROM t
GROUP BY NAME, ROLLUP(TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmMon'));


+-----------------+
|NAME |MON  |SUM_W|
+-----------------+
|adam |Feb  |200  |
|adam |Jan  |200  |
|adam |Mar  |200  |
|adam |total|600  |
|jhone|Feb  |200  |
|jhone|Jan  |100  |
|jhone|Mar  |151  |
|jhone|total|451  |
+-----------------+
```

If you need to transpose your result, you can `PIVOT` it:

```
WITH t(NAME, dt, w) AS (
    SELECT 'adam', DATE '2020-01-01', 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'adam', DATE '2020-02-01', 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'adam', DATE '2020-03-01', 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'jhone', DATE '2020-01-01', 100 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'jhone', DATE '2020-02-01', 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'jhone', DATE '2020-03-01', 151 FROM dual
    )
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT NAME, NVL(TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmMon'), 'total') AS mon, SUM(w) AS sum_w
    FROM t
    GROUP BY NAME, ROLLUP(TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmMon'))
    )
PIVOT (
   SUM(sum_w)
   FOR mon IN ('Jan','Feb','Mar','total')
    );
    
+-------------------------------+
|NAME |'Jan'|'Feb'|'Mar'|'total'|
+-------------------------------+
|adam |200  |200  |200  |600    |
|jhone|100  |200  |151  |451    |
+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
Select name,
       Sum(case when to_char(date,'mon') = 'jan' then wages end) as jan,
       Sum(case when to_char(date,'mon') = 'feb' then wages end) as feb,
       ...
       Sum(wages) as total
From yourTable
Group by name;
```

You need to use the where condition to only consider one year data.